# Referencing a Blazor component RenderFragment inline rather than as nested child

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I currently have two razor components:

- A `ParentComponent` with a `RenderFragment<object>` parameter named `Template`
- A `NestedDisplayComponent` that is used within the template.

I typically render this arrangement like this:

```
<ParentComponent>
    <Template>
        <NestedDisplayComponent />
    </Template>
</ParentComponent>
```

I would love to be able to do this inline, like:

```
<ParentComponent Template="NestedDisplayComponent" />
```

but I haven't been able to work out the syntax to convert the `NestedDisplayComponent` into a consumable 'RenderFragment' at this point. I did work through calling the `BuildRenderTree`, and passing that result in, but it's more confusing syntax than just the additional nested lines.

Is there a way to do this inline?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I'm assuming this is a simplistic example (and await the complications!)

A RenderFragment is a delegate with the pattern `void Method(RenderTreeBuilder builder)`.  Any method that fits the pattern can be assigned to a `RenderFragment` Parameter.  It's neither a string, nor a component which I think you were hoping for.

There are various ways to do this, all as long as or longer than the original, but canned so you can re-use them.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<MyComponent Template=this.template />

<MyComponent Template=this.template1 />

<MyComponent ComponentType=typeof(NestedComponent) Attributes="@(new Dictionary<string, object> { {"class","bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2"}})" />

@code {
    private RenderFragment template => __builder =>
    {
     <NestedComponent>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
                Blazor
        </div>
     </NestedComponent>
    };

    private RenderFragment template1 => builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<NestedComponent>(1);
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

*MyComponent.razor*

```cs
@if(this.Template is not null)
{
    <div class="bg-light p-2 m-2">
        @this.Template
    </div>
}
else if(this.ComponentType is not null)
{
    <div class="bg-light p-2 m-2">
        <DynamicComponent Type=this.ComponentType Parameters=this.Attributes />
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? Template { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Type? ComponentType { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Dictionary<string, object>? Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

*NestedComponent*

```cs
<h3 @attributes=this.InputAttributes>NestedComponent</h3>
@this.ChildContent

@code {
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public Dictionary<string, object>? InputAttributes { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

Main.razor:

```
<ParentComponent ChildType=typeof(NestedDisplayComponent) />
<ParentComponent ChildType=typeof(NestedDisplayComponent2) />
```

ParentComponent.razor:

```
@CreateComponent(ChildType)

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Type ChildType { get; set; }

    private RenderFragment CreateComponent(Type t) => builder =>
    {
           builder.OpenComponent(0, t);
           builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

NestedDisplayComponent.razor:

```
<h1>NestedDisplayComponent</h1>
```

NestedDisplayComponent2.razor:

```
<h1>NestedDisplayComponent2</h1>
```

Working example:
https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/QnunFVkt02WYrqrR14